# Ubuntu - Why do I have so many Oracle Java 7s, and which one should I be using?

Tags: java, linux, oracle, ubuntu, jvm

I just want to use Oracle's Java 7 JVM to make sure Eclipse is running as fast as it can.  What is going here? Which one should I choose?

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 4 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java          1055      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1051      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java              1         manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java          1055      manual mode
  4            /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0/bin/java                   3         manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Comment: Looks like you have multiple JVMs installed, including a JDK

Comment: Also, if you want Eclipse to be as fast as it can, it is my experience that you should focus on RAM.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This ...

`0   /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java`

... is Oracle JDK's bundled JRE.  This ...

`1   /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java`

... is Open JDK's bundled JRE.   This ...

`2   /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java`

... is Oracle's JDK.  This ...

`3   /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java`

... is a repeat of number 1.  This ...

`4   /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0/bin/java`

... is an independent JRE (probably Oracle`s but I don't know because it doesn't say on the file path).

I will for the moment assume you know the different between JDK and JRE. Every JDK has a bundled JRE. They will be usually in the JDK install folder name JRE.

Oracle's JDK and JRE is a bit better than OpenJDK so I suggest you use `0` for runtime and `2` for development.

Answer (score 0):

Try running each of those path with `-version` to see what they say to be. Say:

```
$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java -version
```

You can then check with `aptitude search jdk` to see what packages you have installed, for example, and try to match them.